# How to get when was the value updated in redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I am using Redis for the cache, I want to update the cache based on when updated last time.

Is there any way to get when was the value updated?

Comment: It's inefficient for Redis to update the cache together with the timestamp. Might consider concatenate a timestamp to the value as you update it?

Comment: Check the doc for Redis keyspace notification.